# Eslint not defined issue with imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, eslint

I have an App.js file like this:

```
import './bootstrap';

if (document.getElementById('vue')) {
    new Vue({
    });
}
```

It imports a bootstrap javascript file which holds the Vue npm package(node module).

In my bootstrap file I import it like so:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

When I run eslint with this setup though I get told:

> 'Vue' is not defined.

If the eslinter only checks per file this seems really obvious since the actually Vue variable is defined in a file that is imported. Can this be fixed cleanly though or do I have to edit my `.eslintrc.js` for a case like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe ES6 imports only apply to the current file (which is the main benefit of a module system – to avoid global contamination). Importing a module without bindings won't also make that module's imports available; they remain scoped to that module only.

You have a few options:

1. You can explicitly import it everywhere you need it (the intended way with modules).

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue';
   ```
2. You can export Vue (and anything else) from your bootstrap file and import everything:

   In bootstrap.js:

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue';
   export { Vue };
   ```

   In App.js:

   ```
   import * as bootstrap from './bootstrap';
   const Vue = bootstrap.Vue;
   ```
3. You can make Vue global from in your bootstrap file, but it defeats the benefit of modules:
   `window.Vue = Vue;`

The [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) articles at MDN give a good overview of different possible ways of importing and exporting.

Comment: I'm aware in this example that #2 is pretty pointless as you're not saving yourself any code, as you could just replace _const Vue = bootstrap.Vue;_ with _import Vue from 'vue';_ in the first place, but I hope it demonstrates the ability to target exports from your bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try few [configuration](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) of eslint in `.eslintrc` to get this working. This error is coming with [es6-modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html), you can try playing with following config:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried out a bunch. Does not seem to work I'm afraid. Thanks for your comment though. If anybody else might have some ideas, they would be more than welcome.

Comment: @Stephan-v I hope you have given it in proper way, check this [link](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options)